# excel how do I count the number of rows containing data?

Tags: excel, multidimensional-array, row, formula, countif

In Excel, I am attempting to count the number of rows that contain data in a 31 by 17 table.  The following formula does the job, but it is cumbersome and not dynamic.  Is there a way to improve this formula using a function or array formula?

```
=SUM(IF(SUM(B3:AF3)>0,1),IF(SUM(B4:AF4)>0,1),IF(SUM(B5:AF5)>0,1),IF(SUM(B6:AF6)>0,1),IF(SUM(B7:AF7)>0,1),IF(SUM(B8:AF8)>0,1),IF(SUM(B9:AF9)>0,1),IF(SUM(B10:AF10)>0,1),IF(SUM(B11:AF11)>0,1),IF(SUM(B12:AF12)>0,1),IF(SUM(B13:AF13)>0,1),IF(SUM(B14:AF14)>0,1),IF(SUM(B15:AF15)>0,1),IF(SUM(B16:AF16)>0,1),IF(SUM(B17:AF17)>0,1),IF(SUM(B18:AF18)>0,1),IF(SUM(B19:AF19)>0,1))
```

Possible answers that i haven't gotten to work have been DBCOUNTA() and SUMPRODUCT(--(SUMIFS)).

Answer (score 1):

There are three general approaches to this problem.

The first - and arguably most sensible (and certainly easiest to understand) - option is to make use of an additional column within your existing table. For example, assuming we use column AG for this purpose, we would enter this formula in `AG3`:

`=COUNT(B3:AF3)>0`

and copy down as required.

After which your count is obtained via simply:

`=COUNTIF(AG3:AG19,TRUE)`

If, for whatever reason, you are unable (or indeed unwilling) to use an additional column, then there are two principal choices.

The first of these is perhaps more intuitively comprehensible, though suffers from the fact that it is volatile, viz:

`=SUMPRODUCT(0+(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(B3:AF3,ROW(B3:AF19)-MIN(ROW(B3:AF19)),))>0))`

The alternative, non-volatile (and therefore preferable, in my opinion) construction, is the following **array formula****:

`=SUM(0+(MMULT(0+(LEN(B3:AF19)>0),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B3:AF19)^0))>0))`

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Thanks for the single cell solutions, those are what I was aiming for!  They still count rows that contain the zero digit, but if I find and replace all 0's with no value, the expected answer of, say 11, is returned.

Comment: Ah, apologies. I hadn't considered zeroes were to be excluded, as you stated to "count the number of rows that contain data", and I would consider zeroes to be valid "data". Perhaps you should have stated "count the number of rows that contain non-zero numerics"? That said, I can amend my solutions if you like?

Comment: You're correct, I must have been typing faster than I was thinking.  If it's no bother, can you add the solution that would count rows containing non-zero numerics so I can learn by contrast?

Comment: For which of the three original solutions do you require the amended version?

Comment: This is the one:  =SUMPRODUCT(0+(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(B3:AF3,ROW(B3:AF19)-MIN(ROW(B3:AF19)),))>0))

Comment: Are all entries within the range numeric? Also, can I ask why you prefer the volatile solution over the non-volatile one?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 17 rows, then try:

```
=(COUNTA(1:1)>0)+(COUNTA(2:2)>0)+(COUNTA(3:3)>0)+(COUNTA(4:4)>0)+(COUNTA(5:5)>0)+(COUNTA(6:6)>0)+(COUNTA(7:7)>0)+(COUNTA(8:8)>0)+(COUNTA(9:9)>0)+(COUNTA(10:10)>0)+(COUNTA(11:11)>0)+(COUNTA(12:12)>0)+(COUNTA(13:13)>0)+(COUNTA(14:14)>0)+(COUNTA(15:15)>0)+(COUNTA(16:16)>0)+(COUNTA(17:17)>0)
```